# Zend Framework: Controllers in separate directories

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm quite new in Zend framework, but quickly learning. I've encountered the following problem, but I don't really know if my solution is good :)

I've created an application which uses widgets. Widget is a class which implements Widget_Interface and is executed by Widget_Manager.

Widgets can be loaded via `WidgetController` (which calls Widget_Manager, etc). Now the problem I encountered is: widgets can also be configured, and to make the code more transparent, I'd like a widget to have its own controller (currently, it is only a class). But the problem is, I'd like all widget configurations to be addressed via `WidgetController`, and then passed to specific widget controller.

An example: let's say I've got a widget named 'scrobbler'. Now when configuring it in the UI, I'd like to make Ajax request with updated settings. I could make a request like `http://myapp.com/scrobbler/update-info/`, so the framework would run `ScrobblerController` and I'd process the information from here on.
My idea is to make a request on `http://myapp.com/widget/update/scrobbler/`, so the framework runs `WidgetController`. `WidgetController` would then call `ScrobblerController` and pass other parameters.

I'm aware of `_forward()` function in `Zend_Controller`, but I'd like to have widget controllers and my application's controllers separated (let's say application controllers in /application/controllers and widget controllers in /application/controllers/widgets).

Is it possible to make this and what do I have to add to the Zend framework configuration? Hope I didn't complicate too much :)

Nice day

**Edit:**
Solved this using modular structure, and moved common classes into root directory.

Comment: Do you utilize modules or the default configurations with all controllers in the <controller>-directory?

Comment: I do not use modules. I've just been searching the internet and found out that modules might be solution to my problem. Now the question is, can you simply access models from one module and use them in the other one?

Answer (score 0):

You coud probably utilize Controller helpers instead of controllers in this case. So let's say that WidgetController is responsible for updating all types of widgets. The `updateAction` would need to find information on which widget type you wish to configure, this is the `scrobbler` parameter. You would need to name this parameter so it can be accessed easily. This can be done by either adding a `route` or adding the name before `scrobbler` in the uri.

**Solution 1**: Add a route:

In Bootstrap:

```
public function __initRoutes () {
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        'widget/update/:type',
        array (
            'controller' => 'widget',
            'action' => 'update'
        ),
        array (
            'type' => '[a-z_-]*'
        )
    );
    /* @var $fc Zend_Controller_Front */
    $fc = $this->bootstrap('FrontController')->getResource('FrontController');
    /* @var $router Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite */
    $router = $fc->getRouter();
    $router->addRoute('update-widget', $route);
}
```

**Solution 2**: Add the parameter name in the uri:

Make requests to `/widget/update/type/widgetName` instead.

---

Now, in the WidgetController::updateAction, you can fetch the widget to update using `$this->_getParam('type')`.

So the code could look something like:

```
class WidgetController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
  public function updateAction ()
  {
     $widgetName = $this->_getParam('type');
     $this->view->result = $this->_helper->Widgets->update($widgetName);
  }
}

class App_Controller_Helper_Widgets extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper
{
  public function update($widgetName)
  {
     $widgetManager = new App_Model_WidgetManager();
     $widget = $widgetManager->load($widgetName);
     $widget->setOptions($this->getRequest()->getParams());
     return $widget->save();
  } 
}
```

Comment: The first solution would work, although I'd still like to see that widget controllers would be in a separated directory.

The second solution doesn't provide much flexibility, since widgets will not only update, but also create different outputs for different requests, so I'd somehow really need full controller class.